# Edit a UILabel from another Class (another ViewController)

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to edit a UILabel which is in ViewContrller2 from ViewController1.

This is my code, but it is not working:

ViewController1.m:

```
// ....

// In my viewDidLoad :

ViewController2 *vc = [[ViewController2 alloc]init];

// calling a function : 

[vc updateLabel];

// ....
```

ViewController2.m:

```
// ....

-(void)updateLabel{

    self.MyLabel.text = @"Text";

    // MyLabel is already declared in ViewController2.h

}

// ....
```

Please can you help me?

I've tried many codes, but it's still not working and I don't know where the problem is.

Comment: Guess: You're creating a new object of class `ViewController2`

Comment: are you adding the view of vc anywhere as subview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rightly or wrongly, to achieve this I would probably use NSUserDefaults to pull info between View Controllers.

*ViewController1*

```
NSUserDefaults *standardDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[standardDefaults setObject:@"This is my Label" forKey:@"labelKey"];
```

*ViewController2*

```
NSUserDefaults *standardDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
MyLabel.text = [standardDefaults stringForKey:@"labelKey"]
```

**Answer updated to reflect amended question for UIProgressView as per below comment:**

*ViewController1.m*

```
NSUserDefaults *standardDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[standardDefaults setDouble:0.75 forKey:@"ProgressValue"]; //value you want your progress view to show
```

*ViewController2.h*

...
create an outlet for your progress view here and link it up in IB

```
  @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIProgressView *ProgressView;
```

*ViewController2.m*

```
@synthesize ProgressView;
```

...

```
NSUserDefaults *standardDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
double ProgressValue = [standardDefaults doubleForKey:@"ProgressValue"];
ProgressView.progress = ProgressValue;
```

Comment: the problem is that this situation is just an example In fact I need that to control a uiprogressview from another VC

Comment: That's a different question really but my approach is still valid. Use NSUserDefaults to pass the value between the controllers, and leave your progressview with the controller to which it belongs, but use your NSUserDefaults value to update it. This way, a value changed in one controller can be passed to your progressview residing in another controller.

Comment: I have amended my answer. Please mark as answered if it has answered your question.  Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new version of vc2, you need to access the one that already exists.  Try sharing a reference to the vc2 controller in vc1 instead

You also need to think about whether you should update it directly from vc1 - you could refresh the label on viewDidLoad in vc2 instead

There are a number of options depending on how you have created vc1 & vc2, and there's a good description of the pros and cons here http://matteomanferdini.com/how-ios-view-controllers-communicate-with-each-other/

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer! But how can I share the reference of the object already existing?

Comment: I've updated the answer to include a link that explains the options nicely

Answer (score 0):

You're creating a new object of ViewController2 class,
if you want to set this value to all views you can use:-
1-NSUserDefaults
2-SQLite
3-Core Data
look to how pass data between view controllers :-
[Passing Data between View Controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that before calling `updateLabel` on `ViewController2` the `viewDidLoad` method of `ViewController2` is called otherwise `self.MyLabel` will be nil and hence anything you assign to `self.MyLabel.text` will be useless. Now to ensure that `viewDidLoad` of `ViewController2` gets called you need to access the view property of `ViewController2` since `viewDidLoad` of a view controller is invoked when first time the view of the controller is tried to accessed.

Once `viewDidLoad` the things you intend to do will work for sure.
To confirm that this is indeed the problem, keep a breakpoint in the `-(void)updateLabel` method and analyze the to see if `self.MyLabel` is nil or not.

Comment: i ve tried to call `[vc viewDidLoad];` before calling `updateLabel` but it's still not working

Comment: you should not call `viewDidLoad` explicitly. Try accessing `vc.view`. For now jus print the frame of vc.view and then call `updateLabel`

Comment: Also did you try keeping the breakpoint? Does sit show `self.MyLabel` to be nil?